# With TYPO3 tx_news, how to combine TS and Flexform

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, tx-news

I have a nearly unconfigured flexform (only set the Switchable Controller Action to "list") which I wanted to configure via TypoScript, e.g. as such:

```
plugin.tx_news {
    settings {
        pluginType = news-list
        limit = 999
        orderBy = datetime
        orderDirection = desc
        startingpoint = {$pidNewsStorage}
        detailPid = {$pidNewsDetail}
        archiveRestriction = active
        categories = 24
        categoryConjunction = and
    }
}
```

The TS is included in the page's setup, and the properties show up correctly in the TSOB.

Strangely, not all settings will work (the custom setting `pluginType` for use in fluid works, while detailPid doesn't). By "work", I mean override the empty settings in the flexform.

Some default settings I have set on the root page DO apply.

Where could I look?

Comment: For first part check if `plugin.tx_news.settings. detailPid=123` shows anything maybe you have not declared `{$pidNewsDetail}`?

Comment: Ah no :-) Also some constantless stuff like `archiveRestriction = active` or the categories doesn't kick in

Answer (score 1):

You can also add here the fields which you want to override from typoscript

```
plugin.tx_news.settings.overrideFlexformSettingsIfEmpty = cropMaxCharacters,dateField,timeRestriction,orderBy,orderDirection,backPid,listPid,startingpoint,recursive,list.paginate.itemsPerPage,list.paginate.templatePath,templateLayout
```